# SQL Query for Running Closing Balance Based on Opening, Credit & Debit Amounts in Zoho Reports

Tags: sql, zoho

I am using Zoho Reports wherein I have two tables with respective columns as under:

**GL Master Table (This consists of Opening Balances of respective GL Account Codes as on April 01, 2017 which is start of the Financial Year).**

[image: GL Master Table]

**Trial Balance Group (This consists of date wise Debit & Credit amounts of respective GL Account Codes)**

[image: Trial Balance Group]

Based on the above, I now want to calculate Date wise Closing Balance for respective GL accounts wherein the Closing Balance of a particular date shall be Opening Balance for next transaction Date. I would like to have resultant data in below fashion.

[image: Trial Balance Result]

Note that as I am using Zoho Reports, it has limitations of developing Query Table only by way of "SELECT" statements.

For the above requirement, currently I have created 3 separate Query Tables in Zoho Reports with Queries as under:

1st Table : Q1_AM

```
SELECT
     "GL Account Code",
     "Opening Date",
     "Opening Balance",
     0 as acc_amt
FROM  "GL Master Account" 
UNION ALL
SELECT
     "GL Account Code",
     "Document Date",
     0,
     sum("Debit Amount" + "Credit Amount")
FROM  "Trial Balance 1617" 
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

2nd Table: Q2_AM

```
SELECT
     "GL Account Code",
     "Opening Date",
     sum("Opening Balance") as op_bal,
     sum("acc_amt") as acc_amt
FROM  "Q1_AM" 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

3rd Table: TB Group_Op.Db.Cr.Cl_AM (This is the final output table that I am desiring, but values are not that correct. Not able to figure out if there is any issue with the Queries created.).

```
SELECT
     t1."GL Account Code" as "GL Account Code",
     t1."opening date" as "Opening Date",
     sum(if(t1.acc_amt  > 0, t1.acc_amt, 0)) as "Debit Amount",
     sum(if(t2.acc_amt  < 0, t1.acc_amt, 0)) as "Credit Amount",
     sum(if(t1."Opening Date"  > t2."Opening Date", t2."op_bal" + t2."acc_amt", t2."op_bal")) as "Opening Balance",
     sum(t2."op_bal" + t2."acc_amt") as "Cum. Closing"
FROM  "Q1_AM" t1 JOIN "Q2_AM" t2 ON t1."GL Account Code"  = t2."GL Account Code"
AND t1."opening date"  >= t2."Opening Date"  
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: You might want to edit your post and add an explanation of the SQL SELECT statements you have attempted so far.

Comment: I have posted the queries attempted for your comments.

Comment: I've edited your post to put the code in code format. FYI, any line that begins with four or more spaces is treated as code. Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. Request you to go through the SELECT Statements & give me your feedback on the SELECT Statements.

Comment: You've clearly explained what results you want. Can you explain more clearly, please, the results you're getting that are "not that correct" as well?

Comment: The Opening Balances as in the Q1_AM are getting repeated for respective GL Codes for every transaction date. Whereas the opening balance of a particular date should be the closing balance of previous date.

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem now. The only way that I know of to return a value that is based on a value in another row is to loop through the table(s) in question. Pull the resultset without the calculated field (opening balance) into a temporary table (sorted by GL account). Then loop through the table, storing the closing balance to a variable. Each iteration, assign the current value of the variable to opening balance, and then store closing balance to the variable for the next row. For info on how to do this, read [this](https://www.sqlbook.com/advanced/sql-cursors-how-to-avoid-them/).

Comment: Thanks. I did the same & have got the desired results of closing balance. The closing balances are also reconciled with our ERP.

Comment: Great! Now you might post your solution as an answer to your own question. That will help other people who have the same problem. (I take it you used a while loop and not a cursor?)